# How to exit leaving docker container running (in jenkins)

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-build-flow

I am using a docker-compose file for two services. One for React App and another for Nginx server. I am using Jenkins to build periodically (15 minutes period). In jenkins's build section I execute the command `docker-compose up --build`. But the problem is whenever jenkins start to build it takes unlimited time to finish although both of the containers are already started after a few minutes of starting to build. Due to not finished the first build another build comes into the queue as pending.

**Now my question is how to finish the build process when the containers are started.**

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3"
services:
  react-app:
    container_name: frontend_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: frontend_app:dev 
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - my_host_vol:/app/build/      
    networks:
      - frontend_network

  nginx-server:    
    image: nginx_for_frontend:dev
    container_name: nginx_for_frontend
    tty: true
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # restart: on-failure

    volumes:
      - .:/my_frontend_server
      - my_host_vol:/var/www/html/      

    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - react-app
    networks:
      - server_network

networks:
  frontend_network:
    driver: bridge
  server_network:
    driver: bridge


volumes:
  my_host_vol:
```

**Dockerfile For React app**

```
FROM node:10.16.3

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent
RUN npm run-script build
```

**Dockerfile for nginx**

```
FROM nginx:1.16.1-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /prod.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

**Screenshot of Jenkins console of build process**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally I have found the solution**

If I run my compose file in detach mode (-d) then it is exited from the console when all the services started to run and keeps those services running in background.

```
docker-compose up --build -d  // <------ Here I added '-d'
```

Before I ran the command without detach mode (`docker-compose up --build`) that's why it was running in jenkins console. And for that jenkins build process took infinity time to complete the complete the build.

That's it !

Answer (score 1):

Use `docker-compose build` to just build images. If you use `docker-compose up`, the container will start to run forever unless you force stop it.

**Update:**

If you want to build your front-end program within the docker container. You should have this at the end of your Dockerfile rather than `RUN npm run-script build`

```
CMD [ "npm" ,"run-script", "build"]
```

`CMD` means when your container runs, docker will run that command. If that command finished execution, the docker container will stop.

But `RUN` means when you build your image, docker will run that command to build the image.

It's different between `CMD` and `RUN`.Recommend you to check details from the official document for these two.

Comment: `docker-compose build` only builds the images, doesn't start the container. But I need to run my container. I want jenkins complete its builds (this is jenkins builds) whenever the containers are started.

Comment: @Shamim Oh, now I got your idea, you want to build the front-end in the docker container with the build folder mounted on the host right? So you do not need nginx container running?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I actually want to exit from the shell environment when my docker-compose (multiple containers) upped. Finally I found the solution. I have to run the compose in detach mode (-d). I have added the process in new answer. Thank you again !